# boto3: S3 bucket put event notification failing using IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I am stuck in a situation where I am trying to use IAM Role to configure event notification on a S3 bucket for SQS.

It works with aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_key_id, but not with Role ARN.

**Works:**

```
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
)

bucket_notifications_configuration = {
    'QueueConfigurations': [{
        'Events': ['s3:ObjectCreated:*'],
        'Id': 'Test',
        'QueueArn':'<SQS ARN>'
    }]
}

client.put_bucket_notification_configuration(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    NotificationConfiguration=bucket_notifications_configuration)
```

But we are trying to achieve the same results using IAM Role instead of IDs for security reasons, I could not find any thing that works. Tried using 'sts', still no luck.  Getting errors - "not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource:"

**Doesn't Work:**

```
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    role_arn = <IAM Role ARN>
)

bucket_notifications_configuration = {
    'QueueConfigurations': [{
        'Events': ['s3:ObjectCreated:*'],
        'Id': 'Test',
        'QueueArn':<SQS ARN>
    }]
}

client.put_bucket_notification_configuration(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    NotificationConfiguration=bucket_notifications_configuration)
```

Also tried giving full s3 access to Role running this lambda without providing Access/Secret Key or Role while initializing the client. But it complains about Access Denied.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working!! it seems like you just need to give enough permissions to the role which is assigned at the time of Lambda execution (Thanks @Michael-sqlbot). Which might not work if you run it from local machine as you can not assign a role that way.

Also, make sure that the S3 bucket exists in the same AWS environment that your lambda is trying to modify. Else you will get Access Denied error. And in case your S3 does not have permissions to send messages to SQS queue that you trying to add for notification, it will throw error saying - Unable to validate destination configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you supply an IAM role ARN then the credentials that you are using to assume that role need to have permission to assume the role. Do they?

That aside, it sounds like you are running this code in Lambda. If that's true, then why are you explicitly assuming a role in your Lambda code? You would ordinarily assign an IAM role to the Lambda that already included permissions to put bucket notification configurations and then you would not need to assume anything.

And finally, it seems odd to configure event notifications within a Lambda function (which is typically something that is called frequently). Are you sure this is right?

Comment: I am assigning IAM Role (with full S3 access) to the AWS lambda, so ideally it should not need any more access. But I am getting AccessDenied error.
This lambda won't be getting called frequently, more like one time execution to setup the environment.

Comment: Have you given the S3 service permission to send messages to your SQS queue? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3

Comment: It works when I add the event notification manually. So rights have been setup correctly.

Comment: @Bharat this answer is telling you **not** to pass `role_arn = <IAM Role ARN>` to the constructor.  If your Lambda execution role has the necessary permissions, it is used automatically.  Here, you appear to be trying to explicitly specify it, which is incorrect.  This would only be done if you wanted to assume a *different* role.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain temporary credentials using a role, you need to call `assume_role`. This means that you also need to be authenticated and authorized.

You cannot call assume role using root credentials. You must be using IAM credentials or temporary credentials. The credentials that you are using must have a "Trust Relationship" in order to assume a role.

Note: Since you are using Lambda, you are implementing this wrong. You need to assign an IAM Role to your Lambda function, then the automatic detection of your credentials will happen in your `boto3.client('s3')` function call.

[AWS Lambda Permissions Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/intro-permission-model.html)

The following code will show how to use `assume_role` in your example ignoring the details that I just mentioned about Lambda IAM Roles.

```
client = boto3.client(
    'sts',
    aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

response = client.assume_role(
        RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::012345678901:role/example-role',
        RoleSessionName='ExampleSessionName')

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

s3 = session.client('s3')

bucket_notifications_configuration = {
    'QueueConfigurations': [{
        'Events': ['s3:ObjectCreated:*'],
        'Id': 'Test',
        'QueueArn':<SQS ARN>
    }]
}

s3.put_bucket_notification_configuration(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    NotificationConfiguration=bucket_notifications_configuration)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I assigned appropriate IAM Role to Lambda function, but getting AccessDenied error. Even though it has full S3 access.
Did you mean to say client = boto3.client('sts'?

Comment: Exact error message from which part of your code? This most likely means that you did NOT setup the role correctly or you have not configured Lambda correctly. Details help debug.